# jQuery 1.7 UI 1.8 Draggable, droppable and sortable coexisting

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag and Drop between Multiple Lists and Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918873/drag-and-drop-between-multiple-lists-and-sortable)

I want to have two boxes containing their respective elements. I'd like these elements to be sortable AND draggable into the other container (where they will be able to be sorted with they're new mates)

I have this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q63nc/

but it seems that the "sortable" property is not taken and, in addition, once I move a blue box I can't drag it anymore. Why this?

Thank you for your patience in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you were having [with `sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) is that you were specifying the wrong classes.  You need to select the lists, not the items in the lists.

To get the functionality you want, check out [the sortable `connectWith` property](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).

The description of the `connectWith` option:

> Takes a jQuery selector with items that also have sortables applied. If used, the sortable is now connected to the other one-way, so you can drag from this sortable to the other.

Here is a new fiddle that shows it working - http://jsfiddle.net/huWYN/.

```
 $(function(){
     $("#left-side, #right-side")
         .sortable({
             axis: "x",
             connectWith: ".droppable"
         })
         .disableSelection();
});
```

I added `disableSelection` so you don't accidentally hilight things in the list while you're moving them around.  It just makes the experience smoother.  You might want to do this for the whole container both lists are in.

`disableSelection` isn't documented yet, but it is part of [the jQuery UI Core as of 1.7](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.7#Core).

From [this thread post on the function](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/07687f11ae23a392):

> It's useful for making text elements, or elements that contain 
>   text, not text-selectable. For example, if you have a draggable element, you 
>   may not want text selection to occur when the user goes to drag the element.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it's that simple! 
But I have a curiosity:
what does "connectWith" do?

Comment: I linked to the demo which explains that.  Click the `options` tag at the bottom.  I'll add that info to the answer.